# How to make awk gsub return a tab-separated line?

Tags: tabs, awk, spaces, separator, gsub

I use awk gsub to replace a string in a specific column of my tab-separated file:

```
cat test.txt 
1   1   2032    1
2   1   2032    2
3   1   999 3
4   1   2032    4
5   1   9999    5
```

However, the modified line is separated by spaces, even if -F "\t" was specified:

```
awk -F "\t" '{gsub(/^999$/,"XXX",$3);print}' test.txt
1   1   2032    1
2   1   2032    2
3 1 XXX 3
4   1   2032    4
5   1   9999    5
```

How can I have the modified line(s) separated by tabs as well ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set

```
OFS="\t"
```

so :

```
awk -F "\t" '{gsub(/^999$/, "XXX", $3); print}' OFS="\t" test.txt
```

or

```
awk -F "\t" -v OFS="\t" '{gsub(/^999$/, "XXX", $3); print}' test.txt
```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="\t"}{gsub(/^999$/, "XXX", $3); print}' OFS="\t" test.txt
```

See [man awk](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/awk/)

Comment: I took this to mean set an environment variable `OFS="\t"`, which did not work for me. I should have read more closely.